# Webscoket lib in Wildfly 13

Tags: websocket, wildfly

I have upgraded my server from Wildfly 10.x to 13.x and for some reason I can't find the Webscoket library

I used to have this server end point annotation and it was provided by the wildfly server:

```
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/ws/qvi/push")
public class MyServerPush{
    ...
}
```

now after upgrading to wildfly 13.x I can't find that library provided. I'm getting this error in eclipse:

ServerEndpoint cannot be resolved as atype

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @maio290 ServerEndpoint cannot be resolved as a type (Eclipse Oxygen)

Comment: Since you're getting the error in Eclipse, which should mean that it fails to compile, you should try to add the dependency in your buildfile: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api/1.1

Comment: Ok that solves it, thanks. But its weird that jboss would remove that dependency from the wildfly in the newest version.

Comment: This doesn't have anything in common with the server itself. Usually you have to tell Eclipse all dependencies which it should work with, since they aren't available by default. The scope of the dependency is "provided" wich means it doesn't get packed with the war file ;)

Comment: I've just realized that it is provided by the wildfly. I can see the jar file prepackaged with wildfly-13.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base\javax\websocket\api\main. Yet it seems that eclipse can't find it